# AHCI / RAID / Asmedia Controller

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata, raid-0

I'm fairly new to modding/ tweaking but not so bad with computers;

long story short I have an msi bix bang x-power ii mb in my workstation/ gaming system cross platform machine and I'm using all the SATA ports
2- Intel SATA 6
4- Intel SATA 3
4- Asmedia SATA 6

I've successfully set up a 4- 1TB intel raid 0 on the SATA 3Gbs but I'm trying to set up a 2- Raptor 1TB Raid 0 on the asmedia SATA 6.

I've confirmed the driver is installed and read the asmedia Readme (says that my asmedia controller is configured as AHCI)

I'm booting my mb in RAID and there is no Bios changes from system to system only the OS drive gets changed; is it possible to set up a RAID 0 with Asmedia on AHCI.

Do I need additional software? Asmedia seems only to be a driver.

Thank you for your time.

Windows 7 - 64 Pro
all drivers upto date fresh install on my gaming OS

Comment: You need to switch the Asmedia controller to RAID mode. AHCI will not let you do hardware RAID.

Comment: I don't think I can... When I read the brief asmedia manual it says to check the device manager; my Intel driver is in the Raid category but my Asmedia is in the ide/...controller category.  The manual says this is AHCI mode and it doesn't give a solution to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they will not be RAIDed automatically. After inserting two disks, you will need to go into the IntelRST controller after the BIOS (I think it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on most systems) and create a new RAID drive from them. RAID controllers usually detect disks by their serial number, so everything has to be specifically configured.

The only times you'll be hot-swapping them will be if a drive fails or if you intend to destroy the RAID array. If a drive fails, and you have redundancy (RAID1 or RAID5, which with two drives the only possible one is RAID1), you'll need to remove the bad drive, put in a new one of the same or larger size, and then open the IntelRST control panel and add the new drive as a hot spare to the RAID array. The drivers will take care of rebuilding the array from there.

If you're running RAID0 and a drive fails, you're out of luck. Replace the bad drive, add it to the array, and then format the array.

Answer (score 0):

You already installed the driver for the asmedia card. After this you should be able to create a stripe using windows disk manager. No extra software is needed.

start, run, `diskmgmnt.msc`

[image]

This will open the following screen:

[image]

In the screenshot I only got the option to create a mirror since I already formatted the volume. However with a raw partition you should be able to set up a stripe.

Best of all, you do not need a special configuration for this. If you ever move your stripe to another computer (e.g. because the old one died) you can access the stripe from there.

For more information see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff382722.aspx